# Prove that $\sup f(x) \leq \inf g(y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, real-numbers

Let $f: D \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: D\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions ($D$ nonempty). Suppose that $f(x) \leq g(y)$ for all $x\in D$ and $y \in D$. Show that

$$\sup f(x) \leq \inf g(y)$$

I've tried solving this but I believe I'm approaching this in the wrong way. First I said that there exists $\sup f(x) := \sup (D)$ and $\inf g(y) := \inf g(D)$. 
$\sup f(D)$ is contained in $f(x)$
$\inf g(D)$ is contained in $g(y)$
then $f(x) \leq g(y)$.

Did I do this right? If not, can someone show me how before I move onto part B.

Comment: You only need one variable $x$. Not $x$ for $f$ and $y$ for $g$. So you can replace everywhere $y$ with $x$. (That has to do only with the formulation, is not hint to a solution or something like that).

Comment: This is an incorrect question. Take D = [0,1], f = x, g = x + 0.5.

Now sup f = 1 and inf g  = 0.5. Your claim does not hold here. 

It should be : inf , inf or sup , sup or inf , sup but not sup , inf.

Comment: The hypothesis is that $f(x) \le g(y)$ for $x,y\in D$ - that doesn't hold in that example.

Comment: Oh did it get edited ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a clean way to show this is by contradiction. Suppose that $\sup_{x\in D} f(x) > \inf_{x\in D} g(y)$. Let $\alpha = \frac{\sup_{x\in D} f(x) - \inf_{x\in D} g(y)}{2}$. Then there is an $x_1\in D$ so that $f(x_1) > \alpha$ (otherwise $\alpha$ would be an upper bound for $\{f(x)\,|\,x\in D\}$, contradicting the definition of $\sup$) and an $x_2\in D$ so that $g(x_2) <\alpha$ (otherwise $\alpha$ would be a lower bound for $\{g(x)\,|\,x\in D\}$, contradicting the definition of $\inf$). But by hypothesis we have $f(x_1) \le g(x_2)$ - so we get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Then its even more simpler.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Given } f(x) & \leq & g(y) \mbox{ for all } x,y \in D\\
\Rightarrow \sup_{x \in D} f(x) & \leq & g(y)\\
\Rightarrow \sup_{x \in D} f(x) & \leq & \inf_{y \in D} g(y)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Now $y$ and $x$ are just dummy variables, so in the last step replace $y$ by $x$. And we have : $$ \sup_{x \in D} f(x) \leq  \inf_{x \in D} g(x). $$

Comment: That's the wrong round…

Comment: @Dirk : Edited. But the result was correct then and also now, only this one is relevant to the post. Thanks !!